# RGB Values of Cells Do Not Update after Color Sort

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on a Microsoft Excel to Word Macro and It's going good except I'm running into one small problem. In my excel sheet I execute a sorting macro that sorts by RBG values. `(Red to Top, Yellow to Middle, Green to Bottom)`. It sorts correctly and looks perfect on the excel sheet, but when I go to check the cell RGB value in Visual Basic the RGB values held in each cell is still the value before the sort. For example If:

```
A(1)Y                 A(1)R
A(2)R  Is sorted to   A(2)Y
A(3)G                 A(3)G
```

Which looks correct in excel, but the RGB values of the cells after the sort don't update.
So A(1) RGB value after sort would still be `(255,255,0) Yellow` instead of `(255,0,0) Red`.

Here is my sorting macro, along with the code that checks for the RGB Values of sorted cells

```
    ' sorting Macro

    Range("A7:L12").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Risk Register").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Risk Register").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("L7:L12") _
        , xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
        0, 0)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Risk Register").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("L7:L12") _
        , xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(255, _
        255, 0)
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Risk Register").Sort.SortFields.Add(Range("L7:L12") _
        , xlSortOnCellColor, xlAscending, , xlSortNormal).SortOnValue.Color = RGB(0, _
        255, 0)
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Risk Register").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A6:L12")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

Here is the code where I check the RGB Values of specified cells:

> In this case I'm checking for red

```
k = 7
With wrdDoc

    If (displayRisk = 3) Then 'Don't worry about this line (is working properly)

        Do Until k = (6 + myValue) 'Don't worry about this line (is working properly)

            ' Verifying that I'm Checking Correct Cell
            Debug.Print "L" & k & ""

            ' Here is where I check the RGB Value of specified cell
            If ws.Range("L" & k).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then

                do something...

            End If
        k = k + 1
        Loop
End With
```

Once again in this case:

```
A(1)Y                 A(1)R
A(2)R  Is sorted to   A(2)Y
A(3)G                 A(3)G
```

The result of the macro execution would only "do something" for cell A(2) because that was the cell who's background color was Red before the sort.

The macro **SHOULD** "do something" for cell A(1) (after sort) because that is where the red cell was sorted to. I've been searching awhile for a solution for this and haven't been able to find anything.

My hopes and initial thought to fix this was to somehow create a macro that would be able to "update" the cells after the sort.

By the way, I know that my code does not match with the example I gave.

> IMPORTANT: After the sort- If I were to go to the sorted cells and "re-update" their color `(Literally pressing their fill to the same color it appears on excel)`, the code where I check for the cell's `RGB Value` then works perfectly.

Hope that was clear ^

Comment: What version of Excel? I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Are your cells colored using conditional formatting?  If Yes then you need to use `ws.Range("L" & k).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color` to get the fill color.

Comment: @TimWilliams ws.Range("L" & k).DisplayFormat.Interior.Color worked! Thank you so much